# Getting sub array of character array

Tags: java

Suppose I have character array containing elements `{'.','-','.','-','-'}`.
And I want to retrieve sub array `{'.','-'}` and convert this into string as `".-"`.
I have used the following statement

```
String temp = Arrays.toString((Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,2)));
```

But when I print temp then it prints `[.,-]` that is `temp = "[.,-]"`.
So temp is impure string and I only want `{'.','-'}` these character in temp that is `temp =".-"`.

What should I do?

Comment: for something simple like this perhaps use: `Arrays.toString((Arrays.copyOfRange(a,0,2))).replaceAll("\\s+|\\[|\\]|,", "");`. Here we simply remove the characters we don't want that the Arrays.toString() method produces with the String.replaceAll() method utilizing a Regular Expression. The regular expression is basically saying replace all whitespaces (**\\s+**) if encountered or replace all open square brackets (**\\\[**) if encountered or replace all close square brackets (**\\\]**) if encountered or replace all commas (**,**) if encountered and replace them with a null string (nothing).

Comment: @AxelH - I never said it was simpler. It's just another way among **many** ways. But comma is not present in the provided array ;)

Comment: @AxelH - Uhhh...I see...English is obviously not your native language.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) will build a `String` like `[ <cell0>, <cell1>, <cell2>, ..., <celln>]` as explain in the doc :

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(char). Returns "null" if a is null.

This explains why you get `"[., -]"` But you can correct `String` representation of a `char[]` with the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29)

> `public String(char[] value)`
>
> Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument [...]

Or the static method [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%5B%5D%29)

> `public static String valueOf(char[] data)`
>
> Returns the string representation of the char array argument [...]

```
String s1 = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,2));
String s2 = String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

`String temp = String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,2));`

Answer (score -1):

Use this part for your code:

`String temp=String.valueOf((Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,2)));`